# Get N max numbers from a List<int> using lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, lambda

This is my list:

```
List<int> numbers=new List<int> { 12, 5, -8, 4, 7, 28, 3, 22 };
```

How can I get 4 maximum numbers by lambda: I need these ones:  `{28, 22, 12, 7}`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use:

```
var result = numbers.OrderByDescending(n => n).Take(4);
```

Comment: Note that for a much bigger list it's better to not sort it, and instead go through the list once and keep track of the four largest ints encountered.

Comment: Ins't linq lazy, so that it will do that optimalization as it knows you want only 4?

Comment: You need to sort the numbers first to know *which* 4 to take - `OrderBy` will always fully enumerate the source

Comment: @Aphelion Linq-to-SQL is lazy/delay executed. Linq-to-Objects may not be and usually isn't.

Comment: @ kirill Polishchuk: 
What if we need to keep the original position( index) of our m maximum numbers) ?

Comment: @farzinparsa `var result = numbers.Select((n, idx)=>new {n, idx}).OrderByDescending(n=>n.n);`

Comment: @ kirill Polishchuk:
mine is not a list, it is a double[,] array as [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203766/get-n-max-numbers-and-their-corresponding-positionindex-from-a-listint-using ]