# Get N max numbers and their corresponding position(index) from a 2D array double[,] using lambda expression

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

This is a question similar to [ [Get N max numbers from a List<int> using lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062155/get-n-max-numbers-from-a-listint-using-lambda-expression) ]

But I want to learn if I want to keep the index of those N max numbers, how should I write it using lambda expression.

Example) `List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 12, 5, -8, 4, 7, 28, 3, 22 };`

How can we get 4 maximum numbers by lambda: `{28, 22, 12, 7}` plus indexes `{ 5, 7, 0, 4}`

as [kirill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/787016/kirill-polishchuk) suggested: `var result = numbers.OrderByDescending(n => n).Take(4);` but how can I get the **index of those N max numbers**? and it is a double[,] 2D array ( Not a list )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to note: `OrderBy + Take` is an O(N*Log(N)) operation where "Top N" can be done much faster. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9773/optimizing-liststring-performance-in-c/9777#9777

Said that;

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 12, 5, -8, 4, 7, 28, 3, 22 };
var list = numbers.Select((n, i) => new { Num=n, Inx=i })
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Num)
                    .Take(4)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: what if it is not a list, I mean it is a double[,] array?

Comment: @farzinparsa SO is full of answers about mapping  `double[,]` to  `double[]`

Comment: SO? what does that stand for?